# Не получается настроить логгирование с помощью SLF4J

Tags: java, maven, slf4j

Подключаю следующие зависимости в pom.xml

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Создал и поместил в src/main/resources файл logback.xml

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
        by default -->
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level  %logger{20} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>slf4jlogbackexample.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>slf4jlogbackexample.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>

        <!-- Храним файлы логов 10 дней -->
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>

        <!-- Максимальный размер файлов лога 30 гигабайт -->
        <totalSizeCap>10GB</totalSizeCap>

    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level  %logger{20} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Но при запуске постоянно выскакивает

SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.

Читал [коды ошибок](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings)

Но вроде у меня всё нормально. В чём ошибка?

Comment: По конфику мавена получатся что logback-classic доступен в classpath только во время запуска тестов, т.к. указан скоуп: `<scope>test</scope>`.

Comment: Точно! Забыл поменять. Спасибо большое.